Error: There are no 'Public' subnet groups in this VPC. Available types:
I'm creating a custom Vpc() (i.e a new Vpc() with NO subnetConfiguration)
    this.vpc = new Vpc(this, 'default', {
      vpcName: `${this.props.company.prefix}-vpc`,
      ipAddresses: IpAddresses.cidr('10.0.0.0/16'),
      natGateways: 0,
      createInternetGateway: false,
      enableDnsSupport: true,
      enableDnsHostnames: true,
      **subnetConfiguration**: [], // no subnets
      maxAzs: 3,
    });

...
    //
    // Create Route Tables
    //
    const publicRouteTable = this.createRouteTable("public");
    //
    // Create Public Subnets
    //
    this.createSubnet("public", "10.0.0.0/24", 0, publicRouteTable);


  //
  // create public route table
  //
  private createRouteTable(type: string): CfnRouteTable {
    //
    // Create Public Route Table
    //
    const routeTable = new CfnRouteTable(
      this,
      lnJoin(this.props.company.prefix, type, 'rt'),
      {
        vpcId: this.vpc.vpcId,
        tags: [
          {
            key: 'Name',
            value: lnJoin(this.props.company.prefix, type, 'rt'),
          },
        ],
      }
    );
    //
    // Create a Route
    //
    if (type === 'public') {
      new CfnRoute(
        this,
        lnJoin(this.props.company.prefix, type, 'rt', 'route'),
        {
          routeTableId: routeTable.ref,
          destinationCidrBlock: '0.0.0.0/0',
          gatewayId: this.igw.ref,
        }
      );
    }

    return routeTable;
  }

  //
  // Create Public Subnets
  //
  private createSubnet(
    type: string,
    cidrBlock: string,
    subnetIndex: number,
    routeTable: CfnRouteTable
  ): CfnSubnet {
    
    if (type !== 'public' && type !== 'private') {
      throw new Error('Invalid subnet type.');
    }

    let subnetType =
      type === 'public'
        ? SubnetType.PUBLIC
        : type === 'private'
          ? SubnetType.PRIVATE_WITH_EGRESS
          : SubnetType.PRIVATE_ISOLATED;

    const subnet = new CfnSubnet(
      this,
      lnJoin(
        this.props.company.prefix,
        type,
        'subnet',
        `(${this.vpc.availabilityZones[subnetIndex]})`
      ),
      {
        availabilityZone: this.vpc.availabilityZones[subnetIndex],
        vpcId: this.vpc.vpcId,
        cidrBlock: cidrBlock,
        mapPublicIpOnLaunch: type === 'public',
        tags: [
          {
            key: 'Name',
            value: lnJoin(
              this.props.company.prefix,
              type,
              'subnet',
              `(${this.vpc.availabilityZones[subnetIndex]})`
            ),
          },
          {
            key: this.SUBNETNAME_TAG,
            value: defaultSubnetName(subnetType),
          },
          {
            key: this.SUBNETTYPE_TAG,
            value: subnetTypeTagValue(subnetType),
          },
        ],
      }
    );

    new CfnSubnetRouteTableAssociation(
      this,
      lnJoin(
        this.props.company.prefix,
        type,
        'rt',
        'subnet',
        'assoc',
        `${subnetIndex}`
      ),
      {
        subnetId: subnet.ref,
        routeTableId: routeTable.ref,      
      },
    );

    return subnet;
  }

In subsequent Constructs I am attempting to interate through vpc.publicSubnets() this is when I get this error
"Error: There are no 'Public' subnet groups in this VPC. Available types:"
It's almost as though if I DON'T define subnetConfiguration[] the vpc doesn't see the subnets I created programatically...
I read somewhere that you have to use a specific Tag() when you create a public subnet.
  private SUBNETTYPE_TAG = 'aws-cdk:subnet-type';
  private SUBNETNAME_TAG = 'aws-cdk:subnet-name';

Even when I tag each subnet with the tags above
        tags: [
          {
            key: 'Name',
            value: lnJoin(
              this.props.company.prefix,
              type,
              'subnet',
              `(${this.vpc.availabilityZones[subnetIndex]})`
            ),
          },
**          {
            key: this.SUBNETNAME_TAG,
            value: defaultSubnetName(subnetType),
          },
          {
            key: this.SUBNETTYPE_TAG,
            value: subnetTypeTagValue(subnetType),
          },**
        ],

Can anyone tell me why I'm getting this error? Better yet, what I might do to resolve it?

The tag does not define the subnet as public or private, the association to a route table with a route to the internet defines the subnet as public. Adding a Name tag will give the subnet a friendly name. I'd first look at my routes and ensure the routes and associations look correct. Next, I'd probably console.log out the public subnets on the vpc and see if you get anything Sometimes if I've been working on the stack a lot I have to delete the cdk.context.json file and re-synth or diff the stack to fix the references. May be worth a shot.

OK thanks I'll try this and see what I find out.

Your observation is correct - the Vpc L2 construct only populates the publicSubnets prop if you specify the appropriate subnetConfiguration.
If you create your subnets manually, then it will not be populated, regardless of what subnets you've added. The construct does not have any heuristics for determining whether a subnet is public or private - it only looks at the subnet type in subnetConfiguration when creating the VPC.
Here is the relevant code that populates the publicSubnets prop (this only happens during the creation of the Vpc construct): https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/blob/0fc07f3762f3af821d742338c7839618a73ced50/packages/aws-cdk-lib/aws-ec2/lib/vpc.ts#L1868

I also looked at the aws open source and well if they are making the necessary associations of subnets to vpc then why doen't the make provisions for developers to do the same? Also, I don't like some of their decisions when they setup a vpc programatically, are you suggesting that I'm stuck with their network configuration? At the very least do I have to use the console to deconstruct/construct network associations? That just seems off...

I can't comment on their decisions, but my answer should contain the explanation to your question. You're not "stuck" with it - if you want to use CDK's native subnet selection logic, you have to use the subnet configuration. If not - you don't have to use it. You can always provide the subnets yourself to the constructs that will be using it.
